# The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-designer, office365, sharepoint-workflow

Here i developed one Info Path form and when user submits the form then approval process start in Office 365.
First approval goes to manager of the submitter and he got the email for that it will work fine.but recently one user got below log in workflow history.

**"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly."**

i Google it and in many blogs and forums they have mentioned that it is permissions issue but i checked it also User has permissions because,After this record i enter another record and approved it with this user and got the email.

and it is also not SMTP issue because i developed and published Info Path form on **Office 365**

Now so much confused what to do.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manoj.

Answer (score -1):

Problem:  I had a workflow that was supposed to pause, and thereafter send an email reminder.  Results: nothing.  Tried: everything.  Got the same error every time: The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail setting for the server are configured correctly.

Clues: SP was sending other emails, so I knew the email config was probably OK.

Tests:  I moved the Pause Step after the email Step, and POW! it worked immedioately.  So, there problem seems related to the Pause Step.

SOLUTION: Following the idea of Johan_0904, I returned the Pause Step to the front; and on the Send Email Step, I clicked "Add Else Conditional Branch".  I never used the "Add Else Conditional Branch".  But I did add the condition: "%Complete" "Greater Than" "-1".  This condition is always TRUE.  And the "Send Email" command worked thereafter.  QED.

Comment: Hi RJ thanks for your response but in this workflow i didn't use any pause step.

Comment: add step and do pause for few seconds

Comment: Here what's the problem is this error occurs suddenly and it's not reproduced by me as of now without pause steps also it's work fine.